# Couldn't connect PostgreSQL server of render.com to psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

thanks for paying attention to my problem. I create a new free PostgreSQL server in render.com. But I have problem with configuring it with psycopg2 adapter of PostgreSQL.
Here is my code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname=os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB"),
    user=os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER"),
    password=os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASS"),
    host=os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST"),
    port=os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PORT")
)
```

My environmental variables are stored in `.env` file. I am loading them using `load_dotenv()` function of `dotenv` package. Each environmental variable is assigned to corresponding values of database info in render.com:
[image]
POSTGRES_DB=assigned value of
[image]

POSTGRES_USER=assigned value of
[image]

POSTGRES_PASS=assigned value of
[image]

POSTGRES_HOST=assigned value of
[image]

- added suffix `.singapore-postgres.render.com` to original value

POSTGRES_PORT=`5432`

After configuration when I run the program it is raising the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sarvar/Python/Projects/web_scraping/bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
  File "/home/sarvar/Python/Projects/web_scraping/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

I would be so so grateful if you help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: This is a SSL error. I don't use render.com, so I am just thinking out loud here. My guess is you have SSL access set up on the server side in a manner that the above connection is not meeting.

Comment: Okay, thanks Adrian Klaver for your comment. Does anybody have any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the external URL provided by render.com directly (ignore the rest params), for example:

```
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://user:password@host:port/database_name'

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)
#Replace user and password with your Postgres username and password, host and #port with the values in your database URL, and database_name with the name of #your database.


cur = conn.cursor()

# Replace mytable with the name of the table you want to query.
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

That's it! With these steps, you should now be able to connect to your Postgres database hosted by Render from your Python application.